# Access Elements in JSON File Using C#

Tags: c#, json

I have an JSON result like this

```
{
   "authenticationResultCode":"ValidCredentials",
   "brandLogoUri":"http:\/\/dev.virtualearth.net\/Branding\/logo_powered_by.png",
   "copyright":"Copyright © 2011 Microsoft and its suppliers. All rights reserved. This API cannot be accessed and the content and any results may not be used, reproduced or transmitted in any manner without express written permission from Microsoft Corporation.",
   "resourceSets":[
      {
         "estimatedTotal":1,
         "resources":[
            {
               "__type":"Location:http:\/\/schemas.microsoft.com\/search\/local\/ws\/rest\/v1",
               "bbox":[
                  47.636257744012461,
                  -122.13735364288299,
                  47.643983179153814,
                  -122.12206713944467
               ],
               "name":"1 Microsoft Way, Redmond, WA 98052",
               "point":{
                  "type":"Point",
                  "coordinates":[
                     47.640120461583138,
                     -122.12971039116383
                  ]
               },
               "address":{
                  "addressLine":"1 Microsoft Way",
                  "adminDistrict":"WA",
                  "adminDistrict2":"King Co.",
                  "countryRegion":"United States",
                  "formattedAddress":"1 Microsoft Way, Redmond, WA 98052",
                  "locality":"Redmond",
                  "postalCode":"98052"
               },
               "confidence":"High",
               "entityType":"Address",
               "geocodePoints":[
                  {
                     "type":"Point",
                     "coordinates":[
                        47.640120461583138,
                        -122.12971039116383
                     ],
                     "calculationMethod":"InterpolationOffset",
                     "usageTypes":[
                        "Display"
                     ]
                  },
                  {
                     "type":"Point",
                     "coordinates":[
                        47.640144601464272,
                        -122.12976671755314
                     ],
                     "calculationMethod":"Interpolation",
                     "usageTypes":[
                        "Route"
                     ]
                  }
               ],
               "matchCodes":[
                  "Good"
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "statusCode":200,
   "statusDescription":"OK",
   "traceId":"b0b1286504404eafa7e7dad3e749d570"
}
```

I want to get a list of objects, and every object will contain the value of coordinates

So how can access these element by name?

I am using C# as a code behind.

Comment: Have you tried using a package for deserialising JSON, such as Newtonsoft Json.NET?

Comment: I am using "System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use package like [Json.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/) for this task.

and easily you can generate classes by giving json string from http://json2csharp.com/

then you can access properties of items as below

```
RootObject obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonText);
```

below are the classes generated from the json2csharp for given json

```
public class Point
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public List<double> coordinates { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public string addressLine { get; set; }
    public string adminDistrict { get; set; }
    public string adminDistrict2 { get; set; }
    public string countryRegion { get; set; }
    public string formattedAddress { get; set; }
    public string locality { get; set; }
    public string postalCode { get; set; }
}

public class GeocodePoint
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public List<double> coordinates { get; set; }
    public string calculationMethod { get; set; }
    public List<string> usageTypes { get; set; }
}

public class Resource
{
    public string __type { get; set; }
    public List<double> bbox { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public Point point { get; set; }
    public Address address { get; set; }
    public string confidence { get; set; }
    public string entityType { get; set; }
    public List<GeocodePoint> geocodePoints { get; set; }
    public List<string> matchCodes { get; set; }
}

public class ResourceSet
{
    public int estimatedTotal { get; set; }
    public List<Resource> resources { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string authenticationResultCode { get; set; }
    public string brandLogoUri { get; set; }
    public string copyright { get; set; }
    public List<ResourceSet> resourceSets { get; set; }
    public int statusCode { get; set; }
    public string statusDescription { get; set; }
    public string traceId { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you already appear to be using `DataContractJsonSerializer`, let's stick with that. The best way to deserialize json is to first define a model which will capture the relevant data e.g.

```
public class JsonModel
{
    public int StatusCode { get; set; }
    public string StatusDescription { get; set; }
    public string TraceId { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Next, decorate the model so it's fit for *deserialization*

```
[DataContract]
public class JsonModel
{
    [DataMember(Name = "statusCode")]
    public int StatusCode { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "statusDescription")]
    public string StatusDescription { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "traceId")]
    public string TraceId { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Then finally, perform the deserialization

```
using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(jsonData))) 
{    
    var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(JsonModel));
    var model = (JsonModel) serializer.ReadObject(memoryStream);  
    Console.WriteLine(model.StatusCode);
}
```

> So how can access these element by name?

The other option for deserialization which would give you the ability to reference the properties by name would be to use a `dynamic` object e.g.

```
var model = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<dynamic>(jsonData);
Console.WriteLine(model["statusCode"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the classes for all Bing Maps REST Services from the URL below to your project:

[JSON Data Contracts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj870778.aspx)

Then, make sure that you add the using directive:

```
using BingMapsRESTService.Common.JSON;
```

and read the string as follows (where `stream` is a stream for your json):

```
var d = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Response));
var o = d.ReadObject(stream);
```